# Referencing Cell for sheet name TypeError: Cannot read property 'copyTo' of null Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a function where I copy a template sheet to another sheet.

Right now I have a demo where I hardcode the name of the template sheet that I want to add.

```
function AddFeature(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Defines Sheet that uses the function
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Client Balance");
  
  //Get the template sheet
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Summary Sheet"); 
  var totalrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var r = 2; r <= totalrow; r++){
    var url = sheet.getRange(r,2).getValue();
    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

    //Paste the template sheet to destination spreadsheet
    templateSheet.copyTo(destSheet); 

    destSheet.getSheetByName("Copy of Summary Sheet").activate();
    destSheet.moveActiveSheet(1); //Move the pasted template sheet to sheet at Index 
    destSheet.getSheetByName("Copy of Summary Sheet").setName("Summary Sheet"); //Rename the sheet 
  }
}
```

I want my script to draw the name of the sheet it needs to copy from a cell. I tried using this:

```
  var fname = sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue;
  var cname = sheet.getRange(1,4).getValue;
```

Where I would replace all "Summary Sheet" with : fname
and all "Copy of" with: cname

and they come from my sheet that looks like this:

[image]

Minimal reproductive example:

```
function AddFeature(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Defines Sheet that uses the function
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Client Balance");
  
  //Defines which cells have the sheet name and "Copy of" sheet name
  var fname = sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue;
  var cname = sheet.getRange(1,4).getValue;


  //Get the template sheet
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName(cname); 
  var totalrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var r = 2; r <= totalrow; r++){
    var url = sheet.getRange(r,2).getValue();
    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

    //Paste the template sheet to destination spreadsheet
    templateSheet.copyTo(destSheet); 

    destSheet.getSheetByName(cname).activate();
    destSheet.moveActiveSheet(1); //Move the pasted template sheet to sheet at Index 
    destSheet.getSheetByName(cname).setName(fname); //Rename the sheet 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem.  Currently we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheet everything you need for the question should be posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment. I have added a better example that can be used to reproduce the error

Comment: Your first two getValue commands are missing the `()`.  It's a common error with the new editor.

Answer (score 1):

The statements that get the sheet names try to fetch the values from cells `C1` and `D1`. Your screenshot suggests that the values should instead be fetched from cells `C2` and `D2`. Try this:

```
  var fname = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();
  var cname = sheet.getRange('D2').getValue();
```